# Create Word Custom Task Pane using VB6

Tags: dll, ms-word, vb6, ribbon, customtaskpane

We have a already designed Word ribbon bar and we have our own styles set. We have a ribbon bar button called 'Styles' and when click on it, Styles model dialog will pop-up. 
Now I need to create a non-model dialog to show the Styles as like as the the Word in-built Styles pane.

`<dialogBoxLauncher >
      <button idMso="StylesPane" />
 </dialogBoxLauncher>`

Our product's final output is a .dll and a Word Ribbon bar (.dotm). 
Is it possible to overWrite the StylesPane iDMso to only show our Styles set within the task pane?

If can't, then . I have to create a custom task pane to hold those styles. 
I found this [article](http://www.access-im-unternehmen.de/528) on "Creating a custom task pane using VB6". 
But it is about Visual Basic AddIns.

I tried to find articles on web. But I was unable to find a good article.

It is really appreciated, if somebody can instruct what is need to do in this case.

Thank you.

Comment: research the concept of "repurposing ribbon xml commands". It is possible to use `onAction` to have a built-in command run other code, although I've never tried it with the scenario you propose. Custom Task Pane: should be possible if you're using IDTExtensibility2; research `IDTExtensibility2 VB6 COM Add-in custom task pane` although I don't find anything for VB6, only for .NET - the principles should be the same, however.